# Wipe a string but keep its middle part

Tags: javascript, regex, perl, string, replace

With a string like "HorsieDoggieBirdie", is there a non-capturing regex replace that would kill "Horsie" and "Birdie", yet keep "Doggie" intact? I can only think of a capturing solution:

```
s/(Horsie)(Doggie)(Birdie)/$2/g
```

Is there a non-capturing solution like:

```
s/Horsie##Doggie##Birdie//g
```

where ## is some combination of regex codes? The specific problem is in JavaScript (`innerHTML.replace`) but I'll take Perl suggestions, too.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid captures?

Comment: Well, the obvious answer to your question as you ask it now is `s/HorsieDoggieBirdie/Doggie/g`, but I assume that's not what you *really* wanted to ask?

Comment: The Horsies and Birdies are a simplified example. The real string is obnoxiously long and needs 3 complex regex's to identify the first, middle and end parts. The string is big, so I'm trying to avoid captures which I associate (maybe incorrectly) with a memory hit and extra processing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to capture the `Horsie` or the `Birdie`.

```
s/Horsie(Doggie)Birdie/$1/g;
```

A similar thing should work for Javascript as well.  This is probably as efficient as it gets, and at least as fast as using look-around assertions; although you should benchmark it if you want to know for sure.  (The results, of course, will depend on the horsies, doggies and birdies in question.)

Mandatory disclaimer: you should know [what happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) when you use regular expressions with HTML...

Comment: Nice. The real string is quite big, which is why I was trying to avoid any captures and the associated memory hits. I think I can live with one :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Look-Around Assertions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns):

```
s/(?:Horsie(?=Doggie))|(?:(?<=Doggie)Birdie)//g;
```